# [Talend SF Connection JWT]runtime exception https status 400-bad request message {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"audience is invalid"}

Tags: integration, sandbox, oauth, jwt, talend

I am facing an error while trying to establish the Oauth connection (JWT) between talend ETL tool and salesforce  :

```
runtime exception https status 400-bad request message {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"audience is invalid"}
```

here are the steps I have performed :

1. Downloaded the self signed certificate from salesforce.
2. Created the connected app
3. Used following url to authenticate the user

   https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?
   client_id=&
   redirect_uri=https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success&
   response_type=code

Settings on talend connection:

1. **Name :** Name of the Connection
2. **Connection Type :** oAuth
3. **Oauth2 flow type :** Json web token Flow
4. **Issuer :** client_Id from connected app
5. **Subject :** Salesforce userName
6. **Expiration in time :** 600
7. **Keystore :** Certificate from salesforce
8. **Keystore Password :** password for certificate
9. **Certificate alias :** Name of the certificate.

Advanced setting :
**Salesforce Url :**https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2

[image]

Thanks